# GET mapping : redirection with data from server

Tags: spring-boot

I'm studying Spring with front and suddenly I stopped thinking and have a question.

I'm separating front(Vanilla JS) and back and using axios for front -> server communication.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

On the post page, when I press submit button, POST request to "/post" -> controller saves post and returns post id ->

POST request to "/post" on success GET request to "/post/{id}" on success

When making a GET request, I made it to return the post with the id received as json.

But now that I think about it, a "/post/{id}" GET request, I need to go to the post detail page and get the json data at the same time, and I'm not sure how to do that.

I've looked into using modelAndView, but that seems to require a thymeleaf, so I'm wondering if that's the only way to do it, or if there's a way to use axios.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

i know how to save posts in the database.

but im not sure how to make GET request with redirection and sending data at the same time.

i want to know when you call "/post/{id}", you can see post view page filled with datas from server.

sorry for my English.